# Mac OS: How do you fix a PATH to reach an executable file (in this case postgresql & netlify-cli) without messing up other paths?

Tags: postgresql, macos, terminal, path, netlify-cli

In the mac terminal:

Does anyone know how to set the path variables for a Mac OS, without messing up other paths?

Current folder structure:

```
/
 /Applications
    /[a lot of applications]
    /Postgres.app
        /Contents
          /Versions
              /12
                /bin
                  /psql
 /Users
    /userName
      /Applications
           /[nothing, except a couple hidden files]
```

Right now, if I run the command `psql`, I am getting:

> command not found

If I type the full path:

> /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin/psql

it works, but typing this every time is not practical.

If I run `git` that command is available, or `code` .

Also, I installed `netlify-cli` globally with `npm install -g netlify-cli`, but when I run `netlify-cli`, I get:

> command not found

and I don’t know where to find it in my system

… So, something is working correctly with my paths, and something is not. I don’t know how to fix the problem, without messing up other paths.

Does anyone know how I could find out where `netlify-cli` got installed and fix my paths to `netlify-cli` and `psql` without messing up any other paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Mac OS to be able to find the psql executable, it has to be part of the PATH environment variable, you can check the value of that variable on your terminal with this command

```
echo $PATH
```

what you should do is add the psql executable to it, like this:

```
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin/:$PATH
```

if that solves your problem, you can put that on your .zshrc or .bashrc to make it persistent

Comment: Oh, thank you for this.  I think I see that putting that :$PATH at the end there makes that the path just for that command (psql), right? I was confused about if setting the path re-set it for everything.

Comment: I think when I was trying to set things up, I actually removed my .zshrc file (I don't seem to have .zshrc or .bashrc on my system).  I think I can just make one?

Comment: Also, sorry to bother you with this, but I'm really lost: Do you know where I put the "export PATH=<path>:$PATH ?" I saw someone open up a terminal and show the global variables, but when I search for it online, I'm not finding it. (Thank you again for this help!)

Comment: if you put that on your terminal it is going to  work only for that terminal session, if you open a new one you will not have psql on your path, if you put it on your .bashrc it will be set up of you every time you open a terminal, yes if you dont have that file you can create one, the reason you put :$PATH at the end is because you want to add psql to your actual PATH environmet variable, if you dont put that, the only directory available in PATH is going to be psql so no other executable will be found

Comment: By the way, if you are using Postgres.app you wont neet to set that path on your terminal, yo could just doble click on the database you want to use on the postgres app and a terminal for thata database is going to be opened for you. if you want to install postgres on your system without using the application you should use homebrew, take a look at this guide if thats what you want https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/

Comment: Thanks for the on clicking on postgresql. (I wanted to set up the path, in order to also run pg_dump from the same directory; and it does now).

Comment: I'm a little confused about one thing. I don't understand why the PATH variable now looks in that bin just for "psql" ... My "git" is in a different folder, I'm pretty sure. But it is running just fine.  (Asking because I'm going to need to figure out how to get other executables, like netlify-cli, to run when I figure out where they are on my computer). Can I set up a different path to them? Or will that change this path too?

Comment: your system is going to look for every executable if founds in the directories specified on your PATH variable, if you need to add any other directory just add id to the path using : for separation for example  "export PATH=/directorypostgres/bin:/directorymysql/bin:directoryjava/bin:$PATH" you can add all the directories you need to your PATH

Comment: Oh, so when you run a command, it loops through that list until it finds your executable, and just returns "not found" when it's tried all of them? Thank you! I've been super confused about this.